# How can I solve data binding in Javascript with controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, binding

I built up a drop down list in Javascript dynamically. I want a data biding with my controller but it doesn't recognize that element.

My Javascript code:

```
var mySelect = $('#users');

$.each(data, function(val, patient) {
  mySelect.append(
    $('<option name="clientId"></option>').val(patient.patientId).html(patient.patientName)
  );
});
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public int DoctorSurvey(string clientId)
{
   int ok=1;
   return ok;
}
```

And the clientId is always null, however I selected a value. Can anybody help me, how can I solve data bindig in javascript?

Comment: Add the `name` attribute to the `select` and not to the `options`

Comment: Yes, it resolves my issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have added an answer. You can [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark next to it

Answer (score 1):

When a `form` is submitted, `name` attributes of all the inputs are sent along with the `value` to the server. `ModelBinder` then matches these names against the model's properties or the parameter names used in the POST Action method. So, you should add the `name = clientId` attribute to the `select` and not the `options`.